# Can we declare a vector as template in main function in c++ , if yes how?

Tags: c++

I was practicing templates for first time, so i thought of creating a template for a vector in main function.
And it gave error (error: cannot declare '::main' to be a template). If there is any solution to it, then please tell.

Below is the code I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
int main() {
    T val;
    vector <T> vec;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cin>>val;
        vec.push_back(val);
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you can't do that.

Comment: How would you invoke `main()` with a given type?

Comment: What would you expect when you run this program?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: May be he is doing embedded programming and every character counts :D

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Maybe they just didn't think of this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is a templated main function.

I think you wanted to do something more like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void func();

int main() {
   func<int>();
}

template <class T>
void func()
{
     T val;
    vector <T> vec;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cin>>val;
        vec.push_back(val);
    }
}
```

Here I've created a function "func" templated on T.
When called from main with int in the brackets, it will create the function with int replacing all the 'T'.